# What is the etymology of the word Satagopuram

Tags: vaishnavism, etymology

I would like to know the etymology of the word 'sata-gopuram' (the 'chadari' placed on the head) with respect to the prefix 'sata' (or 'chada')

Comment: The post referred to as an 'exact duplicate' was already read prior to posting this query. However that post merely indicates that ' Sri Vaishnavas started using a crown, called the Sadagopam, to represent the head of Nammalwar (since his name was Sadagopan)'. This does not clarify the meaning of the prefix 'sata' / 'sada' (always? - but this doesn't make sense in this context.)

Comment: @Pandya I too thought of that post when I edited the question but it post doesn't give the etymology of the word or the meaning of the word Sadagopan. They are not dupes. They are related. BTW, The word is Satagopan or Satakopan. But the word Sata gopuram is wrongly pronounced word and made popular by people who doesn't know the correct word.

Comment: @Sinister the answer stats "So Sri Vaishnavas started using a crown, called the Sadagopam, to represent the head of Nammalwar (since his name was Sadagopan), " But if sats is prefix, then it may be different case.

Comment: @Tula Perhaps rather than asking the etymolovy of Satagopuram, which just comes from the name Sadagopan, you should edit your question to ask for the etymology of Sadagopan.

Comment: @Tula In any case, the etymology of Sadagopan is "the one who defeated the Sata Vayu".  When a baby is in the womb, it has a lot of knowledge, like memories of its past births.  But then there's a wind called the Sata Vayu which takes away the baby's memories.  Nammalwar prevented the Sata Vayu from doing anything to him in the womb.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I want the meaning of the root word 'sat/ sata' (?) as in 'satari'/ 'chadari'. Whether it comes from sata-gopuram or sada-gopan should make no difference therefore, if indeed this is its derivation. The syllables have to be individually recognized and the appropriate meaning derived based on philology.

Comment: @Tula ok. I'm reopening the question so-that the etymology of word can be found out or searched.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Your reply is interesting and, for me, fits in with the ritualistic aspect of placing the crown on the devotee's head: as an aid in Remembering. However, this still begs the Q, So what is this ' sata'-ic nature? thanks for your assistance. [Pl share any reference, if used]

Comment: @Tula No, the Sadagopam is not an aid for remembering at all.  The origin of the name Sadagopan has to do with the Sata Vayu, and the Sata Vayu is connected with memory of past births, but the Sadagopuram is just called that because it represents the head of Nammalwar.  And the importance of Nammalwar's head is that it's united with Vishnu's feet, and so the idea behind the Sadagopuram is to put Vishnu's feet on your head, as a way of signifying Sharanagati or total surrender to Vishnu's feet.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: we are on the same page :-) (Divine) Surrender / Prapatti provides the same result. Thanks!

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan From where did u learn that it is called Sata Vayu? Its called Sutika Vayu afaik.

Comment: Article titled "Nammalwars Prapatti to Lord Srinivasa", by N Rajagopalan (pg 31) in Saptagiri: June 2017, TTD: Tirumala refers to the incident. I suggest we treat this topic as closed. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Tula Well, if not answered, the question remains unanswered and will have a bad effect on the site. So, I request you to add a self answer and accept it. This helps the future readers also. BTW, the word is not Sata Gopuram. It is Shata koam or Shatagopam.

Comment: I had used the word 'satagopuram' only because an earlier question on this topic, chadari, on thiS site had used this word which was subsequently explained in the answer.

Comment: The closest answer is that the winds of childbirth, referred to as Suti vayu in the Bhgvd Purana, have perhaps been modified in an imaginative and romanticized retelling of the saint's birth by adding additional vayus that represent ignorance/ death/ misery, Asatah ( Ref The BrhU by B D Basu and SC Vasu). the spelling of course is a mismatch, but semantically there appears to be a decent correlation. The defeat of these 'winds' allows the child-saint perfect recollection of His Source when born, which is normally erased at birth (as told in the Bgvd P.)

Comment: Thus, the vainquisher of Asata, would be its opposite, Sata-h, which would fit in with the prefix Sata-Gopan. Thus the 'winds' would be A-satah rather than Sata, The latter  refering to their conqueror and the crown placed on the devotees head, with the symbolic  gesture of vanquishing ignorance.

Answer (score 2):

The Sanskrit root word here is “Shata” - शठ. In Vaishnavite tradition, one of Nammaazhvar’s titular names is Shata-kopan. Legend is that after He was born, He drove away Shata-vayu in anger. Keshav Srinivasan has discussed Shata Vayu’s significance above. Since He spurned off Shata in anger, thus the title Shata-Kopa.

As for “chadaari”, the word is actually “Shataari”, which would split as “Shata + Ari” in Sanskrit. The meaning being “enemy (Ari) of Shata”. The Shataaris are always placed under the feet of the presiding deity in sanctum sanctorums of the Vishnu temples, and are made with mini Padukas on top of crown like structures. The belief is that by placing this thing - Shataari - which is always at the feet of the Lord, upon devotee’s head, the devotee is graced with the ability to fight off Shata.